# shortcut key to close Find Symbol Results

Tags: visual-studio-2010, shortcut

What is the shortcut key to close Find Symbol Results in visual studio 2010? 
I want to close it using shortcut key with float mode

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a general shortcut to close the ["current tool window"](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=13189), which is <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd>.

Update: In the name of productivity, I procrastinated just long enough to make this list...

## Default key bindings for C# in Visual Studio 2010

---

### Editing

`Edit.CollapseToDefinitions` <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>,<kbd>O</kbd>

- Collapses declaration bodies to provide a high-level view of the types and members in the source file.

`Edit.HideSelection` <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>,<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

- Collapses current selection to an outlining region.

`Edit.ToggleAllOutlining` <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>,<kbd>L</kbd>

- Toggles all previously collapsed outlining regions between collapsed and expanded states.

`Edit.ToggleOutliningExpansion` <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>,<kbd>M</kbd>

- Toggles the currently selected collapsed region between the collapsed and expanded state.

`Edit.StopOutlining` <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>,<kbd>P</kbd>

- Removes all outlining information from the whole document.

`Edit.CommentSelection` <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>,<kbd>C</kbd>

- Inserts `//` at the beginning of the current line or every line of the current selection.

`Edit.UncommentSelection` <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>U</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>,<kbd>U</kbd>

- Removes the `//` at the beginning of the current line or every line of the current selection.

`Edit.FormatDocument` <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>,<kbd>D</kbd>

- Formats the current document according to the indentation and code formatting settings specified on the ***Formatting*** pane under ***Tools | Options | Text Editor | C#***.

`Edit.FormatSelection`                               <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>,<kbd>F</kbd>

- Formats the current selection according to the indentation and code formatting settings specified on the ***Formatting*** pane under ***Tools | Options | Text Editor | C#***.

`Edit.InsertSnippet`                                 <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>X</kbd>

- Displays the Code Snippet Picker. The selected code snippet will be inserted at the caret position.

`Edit.SurroundWith`                                  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>S</kbd>

- Displays the Code Snippet Picker. The selected code snippet will be wrapped around the selected text.

`Edit.InvokeSnippetFromShortcut`                     <kbd>TAB</kbd>

- Inserts the expanded code snippet from the shortcut name.

`Edit.CycleClipboardRing`                            <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

- Pastes text from the Clipboard ring to the caret location in the file. Subsequent use of the shortcut key iterates through the items in the Clipboard ring.

`Edit.Replace`                                       <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

- Displays the replace options in the ***Quick Replace*** tab of the ***Find and Replace*** dialog.

`Edit.ReplaceInFiles`                                <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

- Displays the replace options on the ***Replace in Files*** tab of the ***Find and Replace*** dialog.

`View.ShowSmartTag`                                  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>PERIOD (.)</kbd> or <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>

- Displays the available options on the Smart Tag menu.

`EditorContextMenus.CodeWindow.ViewCallHierarchy`    <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>T</kbd>

- Brings focus to the ***Call Hierarchy*** window using the member at the caret as a top-level node.

`Edit.NextHighlightedReference`                      <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>DOWN ARROW</kbd>

- Moves the caret to the next highlighted identifier matching the current one.

`Edit.PreviousHightlightedReference`                 <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>UP ARROW</kbd>

- Moves the caret to the previous highlighted identifier matching the current one.

`Edit.ToggleCompletionMode`                          <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SPACEBAR</kbd>

- Toggles between suggestion mode (all commit characters except for tab leave entered text as-is, tab chooses a completion item in the list) and completion mode.

`Edit.<Direction>ExtendColumn`                       <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+

- Creates a box selection instead of a stream selection.

---

### Window

`View.ClassView`                                     <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>,<kbd>C</kbd>

- Displays the ***Class View*** window.

`View.CodeDefinitionWindow`                          <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>,<kbd>D</kbd>

- Displays the ***Code Definition*** window.

`View.ErrorList`                                     <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>,<kbd>E</kbd>

- Displays the ***Error List*** window.

`View.ObjectBrowser`                                 <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>,<kbd>J</kbd>

- Displays the ***Object Browser***.

`View.Output`                                        <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>,<kbd>O</kbd>

- Displays the ***Output*** window, where status messages can be viewed at run time.

`View.PropertiesWindow`                              <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>,<kbd>P</kbd>

- Displays the ***Properties*** window, which lists the design-time properties and events for the currently selected item.

`View.SolutionExplorer`                              <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>,<kbd>S</kbd>

- Displays ***Solution Explorer***, which lists the projects and files in the current solution.

`View.TaskList`                                      <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>,<kbd>T</kbd>

- Displays the ***Task List*** window, which displays custom tasks, comments, shortcuts, warnings, and error messages.

`View.Toolbox`                                       <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>,<kbd>X</kbd>

- Displays the ***Toolbox***, which contains controls that can be included or used with your code.

`View.ServerExplorer`                                <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>,<kbd>L</kbd>

- Displays ***Server Explorer***, which lets you view and manipulate database servers, event logs, message queues, Web services, and other operating system services.

`Window.CloseToolWindow`                             <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd>

- Closes the current tool window.

`Data.ShowDataSources`                               <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

- Displays the ***Data Sources*** window.

`Window.CloseDocumentWindow`                         <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>

- Closes the current tab.

`Window.NextDocumentWindowNav`                       <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>

- Displays the ***IDE Navigator***, with the first document window selected.

`View.CallHierarchy`                                 <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W,<kbd>K</kbd></kbd>

- Displays the ***Call Hierarchy*** window, which lists callers and callees for a given member.

`View.ZoomIn`                                        <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>PERIOD (.)</kbd>

- Increases the size of contents in the editor.

`View.ZoomOut`                                       <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>COMMA (,)</kbd>

- Decreases the size of contents in the editor.

---

### File

`File.NewProject`                                    <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

- Displays the ***New Project*** dialog.

`File.OpenProject`                                   <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

- Displays the ***Open Project*** dialog, allowing existing projects to be added to the solution.

`Project.AddClass`                                   <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

- Displays the ***Add New Item*** dialog, selecting the class template by default.

`Project.AddExistingItem`                            <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

- Displays the ***Add Existing Item*** dialog, allowing existing files to be added to the current project.

`Project.AddNewItem`                                 <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

- Displays the ***Add New Item*** dialog, allowing a new file to be added to the current project.

`Window.ShowEzMDIFileList`                           <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DOWN ARROW</kbd>

- Displays a pop-up listing of all open documents

---

### IntelliSense

`Edit.CompleteWord`                                  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACEBAR</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>W</kbd>

- Complete current word in completion list.

`Edit.ListMembers`                                   <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+J or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>L</kbd>

- Invokes IntelliSense completion list.

`Edit.QuickInfo`                                     <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>I</kbd>

- Displays complete declaration for specified identifier in a Quick Info tooltip.

`Edit.ParameterInfo`                                 <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>SPACEBAR</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>P</kbd>

- Displays name, number and type of parameters required for the specified method.

`Make Transparent`                                   <kbd>CTRL</kbd>

- Causes visible completion list to become transparent.

---

### Navigation

`Edit.NavigateTo`                                    <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>COMMA (,)</kbd>

- Displays the ***NavigateTo*** window, which allows quick navigation to files, types, and members. The word at the caret seeds the search.

`Edit.FindAllReferences`                             <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>R</kbd>

- Displays a list of all references for the symbol selected.

`Edit.GoToBrace`                                     <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>

- Moves the caret location to the matching brace in the source file.

`Edit.GoToDefinition`                                <kbd>F12</kbd>

- Navigates to the declaration for the selected symbol in code.

`Edit.GoToNextLocation`                              <kbd>F8</kbd>

- Moves the caret to the next item, such as a task in the ***Task List** window or a search match in the ***Find Results*** window. Subsequent invocations will move to the next item in the list.

`Edit.IncrementalSearch`                             <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>

- Activates incremental search. If incremental search is on, but no input is passed, the previous search query is used. If search input has been found, next invocation searches for the next occurrence of the input text.

`Edit.FindNext`, `Edit.FindPrevious`                   <kbd>F3</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>

- Searches again for the last search pattern in the direction specified.

`Edit.FindNextSelected`                              <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>

- Sets the search pattern to the selected text, then search for next occurrence.

`Edit.FindPreviousSelected`                          <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>

- Sets the search pattern to the selected text, then search for previous occurrence.

`View.ForwardBrowseContext`                          <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>

- Moves to the next item called in code in the current file. Uses the ***Go To Definition*** navigation stack.

`View.PopBrowseContext`                              <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>

- Moves to the previous item called in code in the current file. Uses the ***Go To Definition*** navigation stack.

`View.NavigateBackward`                              <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>HYPHEN (-)</kbd>

- Moves to the previously browsed line of code.

`View.NavigateForward`                               <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>HYPHEN (-)</kbd>

- Moves to the next browsed line of code.

`Edit.FindInFiles`                                   <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

- Displays the ***Find in Files*** tab of the ***Find and Replace*** dialog.

`Edit.FindSymbol`                                    <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>

- Displays the ***Find Symbol*** pane of the ***Find and Replace*** dialog.

`View.ViewCode`                                      <kbd>F7</kbd>

- Displays the selected item in ***Code*** view of the editor.

`View.ViewDesigner`, `View.ViewMarkup`                 <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>

- Switches between ***Design*** and ***Source*** views for the current document.

`Window.MoveToNavigationBar`                         <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>

- Moves focus to the drop-down bar located at the top of the editor when the editor is in ***Code*** view or ***Server Code*** view.

`Edit.Find`                                          <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

- Displays the ***Find Quick*** tab of the ***Find and Replace*** dialog.

`Edit.GoTo`                                          <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>

- Displays the ***Go to Line*** dialog.

`Edit.GoToFindCombo`                                 <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>

- Moves focus to the ***Find/Command*** box on the ***Standard*** toolbar.

---

### Debugging

`Debug.Autos`                        <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>

- Displays the Autos window, which displays variables used in the current line of code and the preceding line of code.

`Debug.CallStack`                    <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>

- Displays the Call Stack window, which displays a list of all active methods or stack frames for the current thread of execution.

`Debug.Immediate`                    <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>I</kbd>

- Displays the Immediate window, where expressions can be evaluated.

Debug.Locals`                        <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd>

- Displays the Locals window, which displays the local variables and their values for each method in the current stack frame.

`Debug.QuickWatch`                   <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>Q</kbd>

- Displays the QuickWatch dialog box that has the current value of the selected expression.

`Debug.Start`                        <kbd>F5</kbd>

- Launches the application under the debugger based on the settings from the startup project. When in Break mode, invoking this command will run the application until the next breakpoint.

`Debug.Start-WithoutDebugging`               <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>

- Launches the application without invoking the debugger.

`Debug.StepInto`                     <kbd>F11</kbd>

- Executes code one statement at a time, following execution into method calls.

`Debug.Step-IntoSpecific`                <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>

- Prompts to select which sub expression to step into, regardless of the tools options setting for skipping properties and operators.

`Debug.StepOut`                      <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>

- Executes the remaining lines of a method in which the current execution point is located.

`Debug.StepOver`                     <kbd>F10</kbd>

- Executes the next line of code, but does not follow execution through any method calls.

`Debug.Stop-Debugging`                   <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>

- Stops running the current application under the debugger.

`Debug.Toggle-Breakpoint`               <kbd>F9</kbd>

- Sets or removes a breakpoint at the current line.

`Debug.Watch`                       <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>W</kbd>

- Displays the Watch window, which displays the values of selected variables or watch expressions.

`Debug.Enable-Breakpoint`               <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd>

- Toggles the breakpoint between disabled and enabled.

`Make DatatipTransparent`               <kbd>[CTRL]</kbd>

- Causes a visible datatip to become transparent.

`Test.RunTestsIn-CurrentContext`            <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>T</kbd>

- Runs the unit test containing the caret.

`Test.RunAllTests-InSolution`               <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>

- Runs all of the unit tests in the solution.

`Edit.GoToNext-Location`                <kbd>F8</kbd>

- Moves the caret to the next item, such as a task in the Task List window or a search match in the Find Results window. Subsequent invocations will move to the next item in the list.

`Edit.Incremental-Search`               <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>

- Activates incremental search. If incremental search is on, but no input is passed, the previous search query is used. If search input has been found, next invocation searches for the next occurrence of the input text.

`Edit.FindNext, Edit.FindPrevious`          <kbd>F3</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>

- Searches again for the last search pattern in the direction specified.

`Edit.FindNext-Selected, Edit.FindPrevious-Selected`    <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>

- Sets the search pattern to the selected text, then search in the direction specified.

`View.Forward-BrowseContext`                <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd>

- Moves to the next item called in code in the current fi le. Uses the Go To Defi nition navigation stack.

`View.PopBrowse-Context`                <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd>

- Moves to the previous item called in code in the current file. Uses the Go To Defi nition navigation stack.

`View.Navigate-Backward`                <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>HYPHEN (-)</kbd>

- Moves to the previously browsed line of code.

`View.Navigate-Forward`                 <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>HYPHEN (-)</kbd>

- Moves to the next browsed line of code.

`Edit.FindInFiles`                  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

- Displays the Find in Files tab of the Find and Replace dialog box.

`Edit.FindSymbol                    <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>

- Displays the Find Symbol pane of the Find and Replace dialog box.

`View.ViewCode                      <kbd>F7</kbd>

- Displays the selected item in Code view of the editor.

`View.ViewDesigner, View.ViewMarkup`            <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>

- Switches between Design and Source views for the current document.  -

`Window.MoveTo-NavigationBar`               <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>

- Moves focus to the drop-down bar located at the top of the editor when the editor is in Code view or Server Code view.

`Edit.Find`                         <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

- Displays the Find Quick tab of the Find and Replace dialog box.

`Edit.GoTo`                         <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>

- Displays the Go to Line dialog box.

`Edit.GoToFind-Combo`                   <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

- Moves focus to the Find/Command box on the Standard toolbar.

`EditorContext-Menus.Code-Window.ViewCall-Hierarchy`    <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>T</kbd>

- Brings focus to the Call Hierarchy window using the member at the caret as a top-level node.

`Edit.NextHighlightedReference, Edit.PreviousHighlightedReference`  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>DOWN ARROW</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>UP ARROW</kbd>

- Moves the caret to the next or previous highlighted identifier matching the current one.

---

### Refactoring

`Refactor.EncapsulateField`                          <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>E</kbd>

- Displays the ***Encapsulate Field*** dialog, allowing creation of a property from an existing field, updating all references to use the new property.

`Refactor.ExtractInterface`                          <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>I</kbd>

- Displays the ***Extract Interface*** dialog, allowing creation of an interface with members derived from an existing class, struct, or interface.

`Refactor.ExtractMethod`                             <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>M</kbd>

- Displays the ***Extract Method*** dialog, allowing creation of a new method from the selected code.

`Refactor.RemoveParameters`                          <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>V</kbd>

- Displays the ***Remove Parameters*** dialog, allowing removal of parameters from methods, indexers, or delegates by changing the declaration wherever called.

`Refactor.Rename`                                    <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd>

- Displays the ***Rename*** dialog, allowing renaming of all references of an identifier.

`Refactor.ReorderParameters`                         <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>O</kbd>

- Displays the ***Reorder Parameters*** dialog, allowing the order of parameters to be changed for methods, indexers, and delegates.

---

### Build

`Build.BuildSolution`                                <kbd>F6</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>

- Builds all projects in the solution

`Build.BuildSelection`                               <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>

- Builds selected project and dependencies

Comment: Sorry i want Hide current tool window

Comment: However shift+f12 doesn't close the tool window

Comment: It was a typo, ALT+F12 opens the Find Symbol dialog, SHIFT+ESC closes the current tool window. Perhaps I'll turn this answer into a list if I get the time.